# Непонятно, откуда margin-bottom у элемента p

Tags: html, css

У надписи в футере есть `margin-bottom`, но в инструментах разработчика `margin-bottom` нет. Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться, как снять это лишнее св-во?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте открыть вкладку "Вычисленные", включить галочку "Показывать все", в поиске найти `margin-bottom` и посмотреть какое установлено значение и каков его источник?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это дефолтный margin для **p**

```
margin-bottom:0
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850594/what-is-the-default-margin-value-of-p-tag

дефолтное значение.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp

```
p{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

можешь скачать normalize.css и подключить его к своему html документу, он много таких проблем решает

Comment: я не понимаю за что меня дизают и хотят удалить мой комментарий, хотя я дал отличный совет